# Worker reload worker init Cannot find module | Nuxt installation issue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

When trying to run new versions of Nuxt, no matter of the npm and node versions, in my case **node:16.13.2** and **npm:8.1.2**, the development server fails with the same message

```
ERROR  [worker reload] [worker init] Cannot find module 'c:\project\src\.nuxt\app.mjs' imported from c:\project\src\.nuxt\dev\index.mjs
```

Suggested solutions such as renaming your folders didn't have any effect on the results.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After I deleted the node_modules folder and package-lock.json it was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

After playing around with both Npm and Node versions and folder naming,
the only thing that solved this issue for me was cloning the project directly to the **Desktop**. After this, it ran without any further issues